# Parsing a SQL table to show parts of one column in two different columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table that looks something like this:

```
|  FileName | Category | Value | Number |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|
| TAG File1 | First    |    10 |      1 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     8 |      1 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     4 |      1 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    13 |      1 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     5 |      1 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     6 |      1 |
| TAG File1 | First    |    11 |      2 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     7 |      2 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |      2 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    14 |      2 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     6 |      2 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     5 |      2 |
| TAG File1 | First    |    10 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     6 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    12 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     7 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     4 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | First    |    11 |      4 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     8 |      4 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |      4 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    13 |      4 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     5 |      4 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     5 |      4 |
```

I wanted to write a query to compare the values of different categories from the `Category` column side by side for different numbers in the `Number` column. Specifically, these values are the maximum value in the `Number` column and the maximum minus 1. The results would look like this:

```
|  FileName | Category |  3 |  4 |
|:---------:|:--------:|:--:|:--:|
| TAG File1 | First    | 10 | 11 |
| TAG File2 | Second   | 12 | 13 |
```

I tried writing a query like this:

```
select FileName, Category, 
    (select Value from Table
    where Category = 'First' and Number = (select Max(Number) - 1 from Table)), 
    (select Value from Table
    where Category = 'First' and Number = (select Max(Number) from Table))
from Table;
```

running that query gives this error:
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: What are the 3rd and 4th columns in your desired outcome example?

Comment: use dynamic sql with `PIVOT`

Comment: @JonathanM Those are the 3 and 4 entries from the `Number` column. So It shows The `Value` entry for File1 and File2 where `Category = First and (Number = 3 or Number = 4)` Probably not the best choices I could have used for the Column headers lol.

Comment: why not `1` and `2`? what is your criteria to select which `Number` to be included? are you explicit about `3` and `4`?

Comment: @techspider Look at my query at the bottom of the question. Those numbers are being selected based on whatever is the maximum value in the `Number` column and the other is the maximum - 1.